# Inserting Header/Footer into newly created word document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to create word document from content in Excel.
When I tryto add header/footer in the word, I'm getting an error "Run Time Error 5941 : The requested member of the collection does  not exist" on line .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header text". Please suggest how I can work with this?

```
Sub CreateFAQWord()
Dim myRow As Long
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim question As String
Dim answer As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

objWord.Selection.Style = objDoc.Styles("Title")
objWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1
objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Title"
objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

With objDoc
    .Styles.Add ("BoldNormal")
        With .Styles("BoldNormal").Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
            .Underline = False
        End With
End With
myRow = 2
' Value 2 here is the column in which questions are present. Change accordingly
While Cells(myRow, 2).Value <> ""
    ' Value 9 here is the column in which Yes/No is present. Change accordingly
    If Cells(myRow, 9) = "Yes" Then
        objDoc.Activate
        question = Cells(myRow, 2)
        answer = Cells(myRow, 3)
        objWord.Selection.Style = objDoc.Styles("BoldNormal")
        objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=question
        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
        objWord.Selection.Style = objDoc.Styles("Normal")
        objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=answer
        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
    myRow = myRow + 1
Wend

For i = 1 To objDoc.Sections.Count
   With objDoc.Sections(i)
       .Headers(wdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header text"
       .Footers(wdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer text"
   End With
Next

' Change the location path of where you want the document to be saved as needed
objDoc.SaveAs "C:\Users\2021282\Desktop\FAQ"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can use `.Range.Text`
Instead try to assign a reference to a range object. To make this work you need to add the "Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library" under references.

```
Dim objRange as Word.Range

For i = 1 To objDoc.Sections.Count
With objDoc.Sections(i)

    Set objRange = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    objRange = "Header Text"
    Set objRange = Nothing

    Set objRange = .Footers(wdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    objRange = "Footer text"
    Set objRange = Nothing
End With
Next
```

Comment: I've tried this and `Dim objRange as Word.Range` shows _user defined type not defined_ error. In references, I do have Microsoft Office Library. And instead of using Word.Range I tried Range type and then it shows error on ` Set objRange = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range` as _Run time error 242 :Object Required_

Comment: You need the Microsoft Word Object Library under References

Comment: I added the library from references and it worked perfectly well. Thanks Niclas

Comment: I updated the code to include the footer as well :-)

Comment: @user2048724 if it is working for you, please accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Chose as answer. Thanks again!